# randomly select and execute a function from a list. Repeat the process and save the outputs

Tags: r, function, random, nested, simulation

I have multiple functions that generate random numbers. All these functions describe the same prozess. I want to choose a function 100 times at random, execute it and save the outcomes (100 rows per function execution) in a table.

For the functions I have written the following code:

```
# AKBAS u.a. (2009)
akbas <- function(n){
  x.m=se.m=x.st=se.st=NULL 
  for(i in 1:n){
    print(x.m[i] <- runif(n = 1, min = 0, max = 1))
    se.m[i] <- 0.17 * (x.m[i]^2) - 0.03 * x.m[i]
    print(x.st[i] <- runif(n = 1, min = 1, max = 5))
    se.st[i] <- 0.17 * (x.st[i]^2) - 0.03 * x.st[i]
  }
  return(list(se.m, se.st))
}
se.akbas <- matrix(unlist(akbas(100)),100, 2)

# FUCHS u.a.(2007)
fuchs07 <- function(n){
  x.m=se.m=x.st=se.st=NULL #solves indexing problem
  for(i in 1:n){
    print(x.m[i] <- runif(n = 1, min = 0, max = 1))
    se.m[i] <- 0.11 * (x.m[i]^2) - 0.02 * x.m[i]
    print(x.st[i] <- runif(n = 1, min = 1, max = 5))
    se.st[i] <- 0.11 * (x.st[i]^2) - 0.02 * x.st[i]
  }
  return(list(se.m, se.st))
}
se.fuchs07 <- matrix(unlist(fuchs07(100)),100, 2)

# BELL AND GLADE (2004)
bell.glade <- function(n){
  x.m=se.m=x.st=se.st=NULL 
  for(i in 1:n){
    se.m[i] <- runif(n = 1, min = 0, max = 1)
    se.m[i] <- 0.2
    se.st[i] <- runif(n = 1, min = 1, max = 5)
    se.st[i] <- 0.5
  }
  return(list(se.m, se.st))
}
se.bell.glade <- matrix(unlist(bell.glade(100)),100, 2)

# BORTER (1999b,a)
borter <- function(n){
  x.m=se.m=x.st=se.st=NULL 
  for(i in 1:n){
    se.m[i] <- runif(n = 1, min = 0, max = 1)
    se.m[i] <- 0.1
    se.st[i] <- runif(n = 1, min = 1, max = 5)
    se.st[i] <- 0.5
  }
  return(list(se.m, se.st))
}
se.borter <- matrix(unlist(borter(100)),100, 2)

# FELL UND HARTFORD (1997)
fell.hartford <- function(n){
  x.m=se.m=x.st=se.st=NULL 
  for(i in 1:n){
    se.m[i] <- ifelse (runif(n = 1, min = 0, max = 1) < 0.25, 0.1, 0.4)
    se.st[i] <- ifelse (runif(n = 1, min = 1, max = 5) < 1.5, 0.4, 0.7)
  }
  return(list(se.m, se.st))
}
se.fell.hartford <- matrix(unlist(fell.hartford(100)),100, 2)

funktionen <- list(se.akbas, se.bell.glade, se.borter, se.fell.hartford, se.fuchs07)
murgang <- do.call(rbind, funktionen)
```

The final output should be in a long format - se.m and se.st stacked. I include an indicator column with values 1 for se.m and 2 for se.st. Here a small part of the output:

```
495           1  0.0228
496           1  0.0494
497           1  0.0158
498           1  0.0169
499           1  0.0357
500           1  0.0436
501           2  0.3459
502           2  2.7998
503           2  3.6571
504           2  3.1501
505           2  2.7418
506           2  0.5286
```

However I am stuck on the prozess of random function selection `get.f`. I was thinking of something like:

```
get.f <- function(m){
  sample(funktionen, 100, replace = TRUE)
}
```

How do I get to save the results?

Any suggestion for simplyfying this prozess? I am sure there is a more efficient way, but I just haven't found it yet.

I am new to R and will highly appriciate any constructive comments and/or critique.

PS: This might not have been the best question ever asked, I understand that you rate me -1. But if you do, please tell me why, so i can improve and not make the same mistakes in the future.

Comment: why not just sample the *indices* of the functions and call them by position in the list? `ss <- sample(length(funktionen),size=100,replace=TRUE); res <- unlist(lapply(ss,function(i) funktionen[[i]](100))` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First an improvement to the functions.  You do not need a for loop 1:n then set runif(n=1...), instead just set runif(n...) where n is provided as an argument to your function.

You also do not need to list the results `se.m` and `se.st` within the function, then after unlist and set as matrix.  Instead, return a `cbind` of the results. See below:

```
bell.glade <- function(n){
  x.m=se.m=x.st=se.st=NULL 
    se.m <- runif(n, min = 0, max = 1)
    se.st <- runif(n, min = 1, max = 5)
  return(cbind(se.m, se.st))
}
bell.grade(4) # where n=4
```

Second, I think you forgot to remove the constants in `bell.grade` and `borter` that you set `se.m` and `se.st` to, you are probably using them to troubleshoot, I removed them in the final version below.

Here are the functions now, (I added a print of function name for testing):

```
# AKBAS u.a. (2009)
akbas <- function(n){
  x.m=se.m=x.st=se.st=NULL 
    print(x.m <- runif(n, min = 0, max = 1))
    se.m <- 0.17 * (x.m^2) - 0.03 * x.m
    print(x.st <- runif(n, min = 1, max = 5))
    se.st <- 0.17 * (x.st^2) - 0.03 * x.st
    print("akbas")
  return(cbind(se.m, se.st))
}
# FUCHS u.a.(2007)
fuchs07 <- function(n){
  x.m=se.m=x.st=se.st=NULL #solves indexing problem
    print(x.m <- runif(n, min = 0, max = 1))
    se.m <- 0.11 * (x.m^2) - 0.02 * x.m
    print(x.st <- runif(n, min = 1, max = 5))
    se.st <- 0.11 * (x.st^2) - 0.02 * x.st
    print("fuchs07")
  return(cbind(se.m, se.st))
}
# BELL AND GLADE (2004)
bell.glade <- function(n){
  x.m=se.m=x.st=se.st=NULL 
    se.m <- runif(n, min = 0, max = 1)
    se.st <- runif(n, min = 1, max = 5)
    print("bell.glade")
  return(cbind(se.m, se.st))
}
# BORTER (1999b,a)
borter <- function(n){
  x.m=se.m=x.st=se.st=NULL 
    se.m <- runif(n, min = 0, max = 1)
    se.st <- runif(n, min = 1, max = 5)
    print("borter")
  return(cbind(se.m, se.st))
}
# FELL UND HARTFORD (1997)
fell.hartford <- function(n){
  x.m=se.m=x.st=se.st=NULL 
    se.m <- ifelse (runif(n, min = 0, max = 1) < 0.25, 0.1, 0.4)
    se.st <- ifelse (runif(n, min = 1, max = 5) < 1.5, 0.4, 0.7)
    print("fell.hartford")
  return(cbind(se.m, se.st))
}
```

And here is the list of functions:

```
funktionen <- list(akbas, bell.glade, borter, fell.hartford, fuchs07)
```

Note the use of `do.call` to access the list of functions in `funktionen`, here we test `borter`

```
do.call(funktionen[[3]], args=list(n=1)) # borter
[1] "borter"
          se.m    se.st
[1,] 0.7996913 1.505884
```

Now it means the index of `funktionen` 1:5 is what needs to be sampled 100 times to randomly return a call to either 1 of the 5 functions in the list 100 times.

```
fxn_list_sample <- sample(1:5, 100, replace=T)
fxn_list_result <- sapply(fxn_list_sample, function(x) do.call(funktionen[[x]], args=list(n=1)))
fxn_list_result
```

This prints the random sequence of functions that are called. `fxn_list_result` returns a 2x100 matrix with 1st row se.m values, 2nd row se.st values. You can just transform into long form.  Set seed `set.seed` if necessary for reproducibility.

Comment: Thank you @R.S, that was exactly what i was looking for. Regarding the function, `bell.grade` and `borter` i mean to assign constants to the on the specified inteval. I have improved the command:     `se.m[i] <- ifelse (runif(n = 1, min = 0, max = 1) < 1, 0.2, 0.2)`. The `do.call` function works great. But i don't understand why R changes the `se.m` and `se.set` to `v1` and `v2`. Is there a way to keep the original names or do i need to rename the `v1` and `v2` manually ?

Comment: i mean `se.st` instead of `se.set`...my apology!

Comment: @Danka, I'm not sure why you want to set n=1 within your function when n is the argument to your function e.g. bell.grade <- function(n) {...} and it is defined when you call your function; similarly you don't need the index [i] as I have explained above.  I don't understand your ifelse statement, see `?ifelse` where arguments are defined as `ifelse(test, yes, no)`.  Your test statement reads if the random unif number between 0 and 1 is less than 1, if yes use 0.2, if no use 0.2.  Why go through a `runif` number?